# Are these "big-O-notations" correct?

Tags: limits, notation, asymptotics

I do understand the examples below, see [1], but I am not shure how to handle
the following four notations, are they correct?

1)$$\frac{5k}{2} \cdot n^{\sqrt{\pi}} + \bigg(1 - \frac{1}{2017}\bigg)^{5n+4} = O\bigg(\bigg(\frac{1}{2017}\bigg)^{5n+4}\bigg)$$
2)$$n^2 \cdot \log(2n) - \frac{8k \cdot e^{2n}}{e^{3n}} + \sqrt{5n} = O( n^2 )$$
3) $$\bigg(e^{\sqrt{k/n!}} - 8\pi^{0,35}\bigg)^{5e/8e^{\pi}} = O\bigg( e^{\sqrt{k/n!}^{5e/8e^{\pi}}} \bigg)$$
4) $$0,35^{0,14n + 1,18n^2} = O( 0,35^{1,18n^2} )$$

[1] Examples of big-O-notations:

```
(8/π) * sqrt(log(2n)) + n^(5k/525) = O( n^(5k/525) )
14n⁴ + 27n * log₅(5n)              = O( n⁴ )
42log(5n)n² + 42log(5n)⁵n     = O( n²log(n) )
(65n + 36π²ⁿ)⁵                = O( π¹⁰ⁿ )
45log(5n)⁵n² + 42log(5n)n²    = O( n²log(n)⁵ )
(e³ᴾⁱ36)ⁿ + 39n²              = O( (e³ᴾⁱ36)ⁿ )
4log(5n)⁵n² + 27log(n)n²      = O( n²log(n)⁵ )
n³⁻ⁿ + 3n                     = O( n )      // Cuz n is negative (n³⁻ⁿ)
(65n + πⁿ)⁵                   = O( π⁵ⁿ )
50n³ + eⁿ⁻³ - 7n              = O( eⁿ )
(12/n⁶) + 794⁶n               = O( n )      // Cuz n⁶ is the denominator
(42ᵏ-k)⁵⁶⁷ᵏ * n¹⁷ᵏ            = O( n¹⁷ᵏ )
1³ⁿ                           = O( 1 )
73n + 27n¹³                   = O( n¹³ )
log(5n)⁵n² + 365⁴⁷ⁿ           = O( 365⁴⁷ⁿ )
nⁿ + n!                       = O( nⁿ )
(64n + πⁿ)³                   = O( π³ⁿ )
n²ⁿ + 5⁴ⁿ                     = O( n²ⁿ )
27n³⁰ + 1³ⁿᴾⁱ                 = O( n³⁰ )
n³⁻ⁿ + 3n³⁺ⁿ                  = O( n³⁺ⁿ )
(65n + 2ⁿπⁿ)⁵                 = O( 2⁵ⁿπ⁵ⁿ )
49n³ + 49eⁿ⁻³ - 7n            = O( eⁿ )
4log(5n)⁵n² + 27log(n)nⁿ      = O( nⁿlog(n) )
6⁶ᴾⁱn⁶⁶⁶ + (101²⁰)² + 4711ⁿᴾⁱ = O( 4711ⁿᴾⁱ )
-1²ⁿ                          = O( 1 )
815⁶n + (12/n¹²)              = O( n )    // Cuz n¹² is the denominator
```

**Hierarchie**:

```
> from fast
O( 1 )
O( log(n) )
O( n )
O( n*log(n) )
O( n^2 )
O( n^3 )
O( n^k ) // k > 3
O( k^n )
O( n! )
O( n^n )
O( infinite )
> to slow
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Incorrect. As $n \to \infty$, notice that 
   $$\bigg(1 - \frac{1}{2017}\bigg)^{5n+4}$$
   is bounded, so the dominating factor is the $n ^{\sqrt\pi}$ term.
2. Incorrect. Notice that $\log {2n}$ is unbounded, so $n^2 \log 2n$ grows faster than $Kn^2$ for any positive $K$.
3. Notice that the function $e^{\sqrt{\frac{k}{n!}}}$ goes to $1$ as $n \to \infty$, so generally one might write this as $O(1)$ instead. I will stress that your answer is also correct.
4. Incorrect. Notice that the multiplicative factor $0.35^{0.14 n}$ that you are discarding is not a constant factor. To see this, go back to the definition of Big $O$.

   By definition, $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ if there is a constant $K$ such that $K g(n)$ > $f(n)$, for all $n$. Then, think about what this means for claiming that $0.35^{0.14 n+1.18 n^2}$ is $O(0.35^{1.18 n^2})$. You would be claiming that there's a fixed $K$ such that $$ K \cdot 0.35^{1.18 n^2} 
    > 0.35^{0.14 n+1.18 n^2} = 0.35^{0.14 n} \cdot 0.35^{1.18 n^2}$$

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Does that mean, that O(g(n)) in case 4 is `O(0.35^(0.14n+1.18n²))`?

Comment: Patrick - that's correct.